# How do I find the Millman theorem in this op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistors, source

So I have this circuit and I want to find the millman theorem of it. I started with it and I got here.
I have E2 connected to the ground and E1 connected to a voltage source V1. So V+ = V1; and V- is where i got confused a little bit. So when I want to find V-, I have on the numerator ((0/R + Vs/R0 + Vs/R1 + Vs/R2) / (1/R + 1/R0 + 1/R1 + 1/R2))
Is that right? Is that what I should do or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal [opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGvmLp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_\text{a}=\text{V}_1$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_\text{a}}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_\text{a}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_2\$:

$$\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{a}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_4}\right)+\left(\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_\text{b}\right)\cdot\frac{\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=V1 = Va; FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2, I4 == I2 + I3, I4 == I1 + I3, I1 == (Vb - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V3)/R2, I3 == (V2 - V3)/R3, I4 == V3/R4}, {V2, V3, I1, 
   I2, I3, I4}]]

Out[1]={{V2 -> ((R3 + R4) Va)/R4 + ((R2 + R3 + (R2 R3)/R4) (Va - Vb))/R1, 
  V3 -> ((R1 + R2) Va - R2 Vb)/R1, I1 -> (-Va + Vb)/R1, 
  I2 -> (-Va + Vb)/R1, I3 -> (R1 Va + (R2 + R4) (Va - Vb))/(R1 R4), 
  I4 -> ((R1 + R2) Va - R2 Vb)/(R1 R4)}}
```